# Can the Symfony2 form builder be used for the login form?

Tags: symfony, authentication, formbuilder

I have spent the last several hours trying to get a login form built with the Symfony form builder to work.

As far as I can tell, the problem is that the form builder creates field names of the form formName[fieldName] (e.g., login[_username]) and the security component looks for "flat" field names (e.g., _username). This results in a CSRF failure on submit.

I have been unable to find any way to coerce the form builder into producing flat field names.

Does anyone know of a way to use the form builder to build the login form?
Is it even possible?

Thanks.

------------ Update in response to Cerad's answer -------------------

Cerad. Thanks for the reply and the link.

I've updated my security.yml to this:

```
    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            pattern: ^/
            provider:
            form_login:
                check_path:                     userLoginCheck
                login_path:                     userLogin
                always_use_default_target_path: true
                default_target_path:            /
                username_parameter:             login[email]
                password_parameter:             login[password]
                csrf_parameter:                 login[_token]
                intention:                      authenticate
                csrf_provider:                  form.csrf_provider
            logout:         true
            anonymous:      true
            switch_user:    { role: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN }
```

I'm rendering the form a little differently than in your example.
I'm using a form type and calling $this->createForm() in my controller.
The rendered form looks like this:

```html
<form name="login"
      method="post"
      action="/user/loginCheck"
      class="dplhUser"
      novalidate="novalidate">
  <div id="login">
    <div class="formRow">
      <label for="login_email"
             class="required">Email:</label>
      <input type="text"
             id="login_email"
             name="login[email]"
             required="required"/>
    </div>
    <div class="formRow">
      <label for="login_password"
             class="required">Password:</label>
      <input type="password"
             id="login_password"
             name="login[password]"
             required="required"/>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden"
           id="login__token"
           name="login[_token]"
           value="ij3CcnLiHzeLrNUDnxXtdExcPvGkgusIEriYmnZmgy8"/></div>
  <label for="submit"></label>
  <input type="submit"
         name="submit"
         Value="Login"/>
</form>
```

The name attributes match those that are now in security.yml.
I Cleared the cache and deleted the session cookie. Still getting CSRF failures.

Form construction:

```
class LoginType extends AbstractType
{
  public function buildForm( FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options )
  {
    $builder
      ->add( 'email', null, ['mapped' => false] )
      ->add( 'password', 'password', ['mapped' => false] );
  }
  public function getName()
  {
    return 'login';
  }
  public function setDefaultOptions( OptionsResolverInterface $resolver )
  {
    $resolver->setDefaults( ['intention' => 'authentication'] );
  }
}
```

Comment: Small note, in Symfony 3 "intention" was renamed to csrf_token_id
And "csrf_provider" was renamed to "csrf_token_generator"

Comment: Will the previous names cause deprecation notices in 2.8?

Comment: To complete @user3433773 's note on Symfony3, csrf_token_generator no longer supports form.csrf_provider service. SO use csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were close but instead of trying to change the form field names, you change the names that the security system are expecting.  Most of this is documented in the reference section but it does take a bit to put it all together.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html

```
        # security.yml
        form_login:
            provider:            cerad_tourn_account_user_provider
            login_path:          cerad_tourn_account_user_login
            check_path:          cerad_tourn_account_user_login_check
            default_target_path: cerad_tourn_home

            # This matches your form element names
            username_parameter:  cerad_tourn_account_user_login[username]
            password_parameter:  cerad_tourn_account_user_login[password]
            csrf_parameter:      cerad_tourn_account_user_login[_token]
            csrf_provider:       form.csrf_provider
            intention:           authenticate

protected function createFormForModel($model)
{        
    /* ======================================================
     * Start building
     */
    $formOptions = array(
        'cascade_validation' => true,
        'intention' => 'authenticate', // Matches security.yml
        'csrf_protection' => true,
    );
    $constraintOptions = array();

    // The name here matches your security file
    $builder = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamed(
        'cerad_tourn_account_user_login',
        'form',$model,$formOptions);

    $builder->add('username','text', array(
        'required' => true,
        'label'    => 'Email',
        'trim'     => true,
        'constraints' => array(
            new UsernameOrEmailExistsConstraint($constraintOptions),
        ),
        'attr' => array('size' => 30),
     ));
     $builder->add('password','password', array(
        'required' => true,
        'label'    => 'Password',
        'trim'     => true,
        'constraints' => array(
            new NotBlankConstraint($constraintOptions),
        ),
        'attr' => array('size' => 30),
    ));
    $builder->add('remember_me','checkbox',  array('label' => 'Remember Me'));

    // Actually a form
    return $builder;
}
```

Nothing special about the template, the form_rest(form) will output the csrf _token.

Comment: Cerad, Thanks for the info and link. I'm still getting CSRF failures. Please see edited content above. - Thanks.

Comment: Post your form code as well.  Need to have intentions=>authenticate in the options.  Maybe post the error message as well.

Comment: Cerad, Okay. I've posted the form builder code. And thanks for hanging in there. :-)

Comment: How are you rendering the html?  Using form_widget or doing everything by hand.  In particular, how are your rendering the csrf token?

Comment: form_start(form),form_widget(form),`<input type="submit"...>`form_end(form). I included the actual rendered HTML in the original post.

Comment: ['intention' => 'authentication'] vs intention: authenticate . Can you spot the difference?

Comment: Oops. forgot the actual error text. " Invalid CSRF token",

Comment: Hopefully you read my last comment about authentication vs authenticate.  Had me going for awhile there.

Comment: Cerad, You rock. That was the last little bit. Thanks very much for the help and the patience.

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer.  It's not that I'm fishing for reps but I really want the reps.

Answer (score 1):

The missing piece to get this working, which is not mentioned above:

This is the controller and the informations you have to put in:

```
public function loginAction()
{
    $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

    $form = $this->createForm(new LoginType(), array(), array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('login_check')));
    return $this->render('AppBundle:Security:login.html.twig', array(
        'last_username' => $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername(),
        'error'         => $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError(),
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

Now, with this you can built the login with CreateForm()! :-)