# Symfony Security: Login-form recaptcha

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to add Recaptcha to the login-form. As i read through the documentation the `SimpleFormAuthenticatorInterface` is accepted by Symfony for such operations. I've added a authenticator to

> src/Security/

And added the authenicator to the simple_form field in `security.yaml`. The only problem is the authenticateToken() method doesn't accept a Request. I've tried to modify the SimpleFormAuthenicationInterface to make it allowed, but still it doesn't matter if you do the recaptcha or not, it still logs in.

Any suggestions how i could make Recaptcha work on a template-driven symfony form? Which uses default Symfony security.

```
class CaptchaAuthenticator implements SimpleFormAuthenticatorInterface
{
    private $encoder;

    public function __construct(UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder)
    {
        $this->encoder = $encoder;
    }

    public function authenticateToken(TokenInterface $token, UserProviderInterface $userProvider, $providerKey)
    {
        try {
            $user = $userProvider->loadUserByUsername($token->getUsername());
        } catch (UsernameNotFoundException $e) {
            // CAUTION: this message will be returned to the client
            // (so don't put any un-trusted messages / error strings here)
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Gebruikersnaam of wachtwoord ongeldig');
        }

        $passwordValid = $this->encoder->isPasswordValid($user, $token->getCredentials());

        if ($passwordValid) {

            // Logic Captcha Start
//            if( !$this->captchaverify($this->$request->get('g-recaptcha-response')) ) {
//                throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException(
//                    'Captcha-verificatie is mislukt!',
//                    array(), // Message Data
//                    412 // HTTP 412 Precondition Failed
//                );
//            }
            // Logic Captcha End

            return new UsernamePasswordToken(
                $user,
                $user->getPassword(),
                $providerKey,
                $user->getRoles()
            );
        }

        // CAUTION: this message will be returned to the client
        // (so don't put any un-trusted messages / error strings here)
        throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Invalid username or password');
    }

    public function supportsToken(TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        return $token instanceof UsernamePasswordToken
            && $token->getProviderKey() === $providerKey;
    }

    public function createToken(Request $request, $username, $password, $providerKey)
    {
        return new UsernamePasswordToken($username, $password, $providerKey);
    }

    public function captchaverify($recaptcha){
        $url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
            "secret"=>"SECRET","response" => $recaptcha));
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $data = json_decode($response);

        return $data->success;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Code is of course not commented out when i tried ^

Comment: You could define your class `CaptchaAuthenticator` as a service and inject as a dependency the http request. So you can check the google captcha before checking the user credentials from bdd :)

Comment: @Mcsky Hmm but the problem is that it has to comply to SimpleFormAuthenticatorInterface, which doesn't accept a Request object. Or do you mean something else ? :x

Comment: When implementing an interface you HAVE to define the same methods + prototype in your class. But you could **inject as a dependency** (Injected from services.yml + _constructor) the http request, after that your code `$this->$request->get('g-recaptcha-response')` will reference the current http request for the php process. And everything should be alright ^^ I can post some code if you need

Comment: @Mcsky I'm still havn't worked with services too much! Especially not since Symfony 4 where a lot of changes were, would you mind giving a small example of the services.yml line? Thanks anyway for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

The service definition loading depend of your application configuration. If you have the default symfony configuration the code below should work, thank to autowiring.

---

```
class CaptchaAuthenticator implements SimpleFormAuthenticatorInterface
{
    private $encoder;
    private $requestStack;

    public function __construct(UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder, RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $this->encoder = $encoder;
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    }

    public function authenticateToken(TokenInterface $token, UserProviderInterface $userProvider, $providerKey)
    {
        $currentRequest = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
        if(!$userCaptchaResponse = $currentRequest->get('g-recaptcha-response')) {
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Unfound user captcha', array(), Response::HTTP_PRECONDITION_FAILED);
        }

        // I think you should check the google captcha first, before accessing to database and manipulate user credentials
        if(!$this->captchaverify($userCaptchaResponse) ) {
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Captcha-verificatie is mislukt', array(), Response::HTTP_PRECONDITION_FAILED);
        }   

        try {
            $user = $userProvider->loadUserByUsername($token->getUsername());
        } catch (UsernameNotFoundException $e) {
            // CAUTION: this message will be returned to the client
            // (so don't put any un-trusted messages / error strings here)
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Gebruikersnaam of wachtwoord ongeldig');
        }

        $passwordValid = $this->encoder->isPasswordValid($user, $token->getCredentials());

        if ($passwordValid) {
            return new UsernamePasswordToken(
                $user,
                $user->getPassword(),
                $providerKey,
                $user->getRoles()
            );
        }

        // CAUTION: this message will be returned to the client
        // (so don't put any un-trusted messages / error strings here)
        throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Invalid username or password');
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried your example above. Still no success. For some reason the whole captcha part is ignored when submitting (when user details are filled). When user details are blank and only captcha is done i'm getting response: `object(stdClass)#422 (3) { ["success"]=> bool(true) ["challenge_ts"]=> string(20) "2018-01-25T22:42:13Z" ["hostname"]=> string(9) "localhost" }`. No data + not filling recaptcha = error as you described.

Comment: How are you submitting the form from the front end part ? It is twig or javascript ? Please link the code :D You could check the informations submitted by your browser by inspecting the network part of the debugger tool.

Answer (score -2):

Another option is to create login form as form type, and validate captcha by callback or custom constraint.

Something like this:

```
class LoginType extends AbstractType {
    /**
     * @var Client
     */
    private $guzzle;

    public function __construct(Client $guzzle)
    {
        $this->guzzle = $guzzle;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ...
            ->add('g-recaptcha-response', TextareaType::class, [
                'constraints' => [new Callback(['callback' => function ($data, ExecutionContextInterface $context) {
                    $body = $this->guzzle
                        ->request('GET', 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', [
                            'query' => [
                                'secret' => CAPTCHA_SECRET,
                                'response' => $data]]);

                    $response = json_decode($body->getBody()->getContents(), true)

                    if (!$response['success']) {
                        $context
                            ->buildViolation('Bot attempt detected')
                            ->addViolation();
                    }
                }])]
            ]);
    }
}
```

BWT, https://stackoverflow.com/a/30104058/1270411 - example of usage login form type

Comment: This adds the g-recaptcha-response TextareaType, while another g-recaptcha-response is already hidden in the recaptcha itself. The one generated by recaptcha gets send with response and doensn't reach the callback. I've tried setting the block prefix to null to fully qualify the name, but still no success